# Check if user location is inside a shape

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, userlocation, mkpolygon

I made this method to check if an user location is inside a polygon on a map view (mapkit). 
I pass to the method the current user location (CLLocationCoordinate2D) and return a boolean just to know if the user is in a polygon or not.

```
func userInsidePolygon(userlocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D ) -> Bool{
    // get every overlay on the map  
    let o = self.mapView.overlays
    // loop every overlay on map
    for overlay in o {
        // handle only polygon
        if overlay is MKPolygon{
            let polygon:MKPolygon =  overlay as! MKPolygon
            let polygonPath:CGMutablePathRef  = CGPathCreateMutable()
            // get points of polygon
            let arrPoints = polygon.points()
            // create cgpath
            for (var i:Int=0; i < polygon.pointCount; i++){
                let mp:MKMapPoint = arrPoints[i]
                if (i == 0){
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(polygonPath, nil, CGFloat(mp.x), CGFloat(mp.y))
                }
                else{
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(polygonPath, nil, CGFloat(mp.x), CGFloat(mp.y))
                }
            }
            let mapPointAsCGP:CGPoint = self.mapView.convertCoordinate(userlocation, toPointToView: self.mapView)
            return CGPathContainsPoint(polygonPath , nil, mapPointAsCGP, false)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I don't really understand why, but the user is never inside a polygon after this test. (and i'm pretty sure he is)

I think it's possible that i have a logic problem with lat/long against x,y.

Does anybody already have work with like this ?

Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are converting the `userLocation` from the map coordinates to the view coordinates but when you build the path, you don't convert the points to the views coordinates.

You'll need to convert the `MKMapPoint` to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` then to a `CGPoint`.

```
let polygonMapPoint: MKMapPoint = arrPoints[i]
let polygonCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(polygonPoint)
let polygonPoint self.mapView.convertCoordinate(polygonPointAsCoordinate, toPointToView: self.mapView)
```

Then use `polygonPoint` when building the path

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(polygonPath, nil, polygonPoint.x, polygonPoint.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3, Xcode 8 answer:

```
func userInsidePolygon(userlocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D ) -> Bool {
    var containsPoint: Bool = false
    // get every overlay on the map
    let o = self.mapView.overlays
    // loop every overlay on map
    for overlay in o {
        // handle only polygon
        if overlay is MKPolygon{
            let polygon:MKPolygon =  overlay as! MKPolygon
            let polygonPath:CGMutablePath  = CGMutablePath()
            // get points of polygon
            let arrPoints = polygon.points()
            // create cgpath
            for i in 0..<polygon.pointCount {

                let polygonMapPoint: MKMapPoint = arrPoints[i]
                let polygonCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(polygonMapPoint)
                let polygonPoint = self.mapView.convert(polygonCoordinate, toPointTo: self.mapView)

                if (i == 0){
                    polygonPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: polygonPoint.x, y: polygonPoint.y))
                }
                else{
                    polygonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: polygonPoint.x, y: polygonPoint.y))
                }
            }
            let mapPointAsCGP:CGPoint = self.mapView.convert(userlocation, toPointTo: self.mapView)
            containsPoint =  polygonPath.contains(mapPointAsCGP)
            if containsPoint {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return containsPoint
}
```